# How can I format a disk and mount it if unmounted and unformatted?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I am running Ubuntu and want my start-up script to check that a specific disc has been mounted and format it if not already formatted ext4.  I don't want the disk to be formatted it has already been formatted  on a previous start up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would start by checking existance of the disk by looking at `/dev/disk/by-id`, then run `blkid` on it, parsing the output for "ext4", then try to mount it. Failures in `blkid` and `mount` would lead to a `mkfs.ext4` and a retry.